# meson.build: ERROR: File does not exist, while in reality it does

Tags: meson-build

From a trivial `meson.build` file, I get the following error:

> meson.build:27:0: ERROR: File dataStructures.hpp does not exist.
>
> ```
> dataStructures.hpp,
> ```

The `meson.build` file is:

```
headers += [
    'dataStructures.hpp',
    'interface.hpp',
    'platform.hpp',
    'progArgs.hpp',
]
```

The file reported as missing is present and it is in the same directory the meson.build file is.

If I remove the 'dataStructures.hpp' string from the list, I get the same error for the second file 'interface.hpp'.

What am I doing wrong?

---

More details follow.

```
> CC=clang CXX=clang++ meson /dev/shm/test-build
The Meson build system
Version: 0.52.0
Source dir: /home/pietrom/myProgs/test
Build dir: /dev/shm/test-build
Build type: native build
Project name: test
Project version: 0.0.1
C++ compiler for the host machine: clang++ (clang 8.0.1 "clang version 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final)")
C++ linker for the host machine: GNU ld.bfd 2.32
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64

src/meson.build:27:0: ERROR: File dataStructures.hpp does not exist.

A full log can be found at /dev/shm/test-build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
```

In the full log there is no much more than what already reported.

This is the project directory structure:

```
test/
   meson.build
   src/
       meson.build
       sources
       config/
            meson.build
            sources
       testers/
            meson.build
            sources
       utilities/
            meson.build
            sources
```

Comment: Maybe meson expects them in another directory?

Comment: I already checked for that, and it is fine.

Comment: You'll have to post more information...

Comment: You wrote "The meson.build file is:... " - but it's not complete, where is line 27 where error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide all meson.build file contents, and most importantly the place where it happens - *meson.build:27:0: ERROR: File dataStructures.hpp does not exist.* - points at line 27 in some meson.build file, I'll try to make a guess that you build executable in root *meson.build* file, i.e. in *test/meson.build* however your headers are inside *test/src*. If that's the case, you don't need to have this array of headers at all, just add

```
inc = include_directories('./src')

some_test_exe = executable('mytest',
  test_sources,
  ...
  include_directories : inc
)
```

[include_directories](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#include_directories) function creates include object with path relative to your source root.